# how do I calculate the limit of this trigonometric function?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{-\sin(-4t)+\sin(-4t) \cos(-6t)}{5t^2}$$

any clues to solve it?

Comment: This is not a do-my-homework-for-me site. Show what you've tried.

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe L'Hôpital ?

Comment: I tried to solving it by conjugating the numerator ,but I'm stuck, haven't seen the l'hôpital rule yet

Comment: Certainly, the first step is to extract the common factor (the sin one). Then, things become something like $\sin(4t)(1-\cos(6t))/t^2$ which shall be familiar. If it is not, go back to your text book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

First simplify the expression to
$$\frac{\sin(4t)-\sin(4t) \cos(6t)}{5t^2}=\frac{\sin(4t)(1-\cos(6t)}{5t^2}$$
Next, you have the standard limit
$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\frac12.$$

Comment: thanks, I din't knew that standar limit, I'll try to solve it

Comment: You must multiply numerator and denominator by $$1+\cos(6t)$$

Answer (score 0):

Write your term in the form $$\frac{\sin(4t)(1-\cos^2(6t))}{1+\cos(6t)}$$ and this $$\frac{\sin(4t)\sin^2(6t)}{1+\cos(6t)}$$